# Opening a .txt file in Java using GSON

Tags: java, json, io, gson

When I run the following code to save a JSON:

```
String regionObject = this.gson.toJson(parentRegion);
JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(regionObject,
    "./tests/model/util/test_saveRegionObject.txt");
```

and after that I reopen the created .txt file:

```
public void test_openRegionObject() throws IOException {
String regionAsString = JsonFileInputOutput
    .openObjectInTextFile("./tests/model/util/test_saveRegionObject.txt");
Gson gson = new Gson();
Region LGNRegion = gson.fromJson(regionAsString, Region.class);
System.out.println(LGNRegion.toString());
}
```

it works perfectly fine.

However, when I try the second snippet of code into a different class that does not contain the first one I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException Failed to invoke public model.MARK_II.Cell() with no args
```

`Cell` is a custom class that is used inside `Region` class. Here is the implementation of the `Cell` class:

```
public abstract class Cell {
protected boolean isActive;

public Cell() {
this.isActive = false;
}

public boolean getActiveState() {
return this.isActive;
}

public void setActiveState(boolean isActive) {
this.isActive = isActive;
}
```

}

My question is how can I fix this exception so that I can read a proper serialized JSON as the one I create with first snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions here.

1. Why I get the exception? This is simple to answer: your `Cell` class (or better your subclass of `Cell` class since `Cell` is abstract) has no a constructor without parameters. Maybe it has a constructor with one or more parameters.
2. Why I can't open a generic file? Difficult to say without showing us the file. It's sure that if you save a Json serialization into a file and just open it you have no error. My best guess is this: when you serialize and save you have not `Cell` subclasses inside (maybe member variables are nulls), whenever you open another file, maybe `Cell` subclasses are defined and so answer to 1. applies.